# How can i access only the first label?

Tags: css

How can I access the only the first label? I have tried with

```
.form-group label:nth-child(1){
  margin-top: 4%;
}
```

however i got no result :\

```
<form class="login" method="post" action="/users/login">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: can u add and id or class to <label> tag in your case? cause it will be a good solution...

Answer (score 2):

```
.form-group:first-child label{
  margin-top: 4%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the first form group and then its label:

```
.form-group:first-child > label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4%;
}
```

Edit: this is assuming you only want to target the label for "Username".

Comment: Thanks alot for the advice, it worked when i changed it to nth-child :)

Answer (score 0):

Revised:

```
.login .form-group:first-child label{
  margin-top: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I tried that however it still selects both labels :(

Comment: I updated it for you you need first-child on form-group

Answer (score 0):

It is because your css goes for the **every-first** (meaning **every**) label in every `.form-group` element. 
You need to change it to first `.form-group`'s label.

```
.form-group:first-child label {
 //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `:nth-child` is to selecting element with same parent. In simple words, say you have a HTML like below:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

The `span:nth-child(1)` is first child of `div` with tag-name `span`. But, if you apply same selector with below HTML (Like in your case):

```
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Selected elements are both the `span` because both `span` came first in their parent which is `div`